# PHP lê dois arquivos TXTs de forma diferente

Tags: php

Tenho dois arquivos txts, utilizei o notepad++ para fazer o texto.

O PHP, lê um arquivo normal com a palavra TÍTULO, mas, o outro aparece T?ULO.

Alguém sabe o motivo, ou como corrigir este problema?

Comment: Coloque o código fonte, uma possível causa talvez seja o encondig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AleMoraes, abra os tres arquivos no notepad++ (2 txt e o arquivo .php) e vá no botão menu `formatar` e selecione a opção: `Codificação em UTF-8 (sem BOM)`

Comment: É isso!!! kkkk, achei que seu "Sem BOM", fosse uma gíria, kkk.
O que é isso "BOM"?
Valeu man.

Comment: @AlêMoraes depende do cenário neste especifico significa: `BYTE ORDER MARK` verifique aqui um documento explicando http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark

Comment: @AlêMoraes no contexto de HTML seria: Browser Object Model

Answer (score 5):

Provavelmente estão com encoding diferente. No notepad++ dá para ver o encoding do ficheiro e inclusivamente alterar o mesmo.

Eventualmente um deles está em UTF8, e outro em latin1, ascii, ou outra coisa do género.